# Adobe Flash Custom Codec

Tags: flash, flex4

Does anyone know if it's possible to integrate a custom codec with Adobe Flash player?  Like some kind of plugin support or another creative way?  I've looked through th e docs and it seems like no.  But I figured I'd check here to see :).

Comment: There really is still someone coding in flash?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

`Flv`/`H264` is the only supported format for any video used in flash, however there are some encoding options available.
See the [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d46.html) and [here](http://download.macromedia.com/flashmediaserver/http_encoding_recommendations.pdf) for more info on this.

The only way to get another video format into flash is to transcode a video with for example [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). This would have to be done server side or pre release build of course.

You can then simply serve, stream or bundle the video with out of the box flash support.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Dennis.  I figured that was the case =\.  Thanks for the helpful links, looks like I will just have to settle for the server side approach.

Comment: There are some servers that will allow to transcode on the fly. Flash Media server does this for some formats. However since it is not free, Red5 could be a nice alternative.